# Beginner question on Ocaml Refs

Tags: ocaml, refs

```
let x = ref 100 in
let f () = !x in
let x = ref 50 in
??? ; f ()
```

You are supposed to get the answer to be 50 by plugging something into the ??? (not shadowing). But I don't know how to change the value of your original ref now, considering x := 50 is going to apply to the SECOND x now....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it really is a "beginner question", that's probably not the expected answer. But I don't know what the "expected answer" is, so let's hack around instead.

```
Obj.(obj (field (repr f) 1)) := 42;;
```

[relevant link](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora115.html#IC-fermeture)

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access original `x` now. So.. shadow `f`!

Comment: It's a problem I'm doing =/ I'm not allowed to shadow.  It was from last years final; the solution shows shadowing, but they didn't intend on allowing people to shadow so they wrote on this practice one "DO NOT USE LET" -- So there must be a way to get f () to equal 42 without shadowing!

Comment: @Paul If the sentence is "DO NOT USE LET", it's easy: `match fun () -> 42 with f -> () ; f () ;;`

Comment: I did not realize you can match on a function. Other than this contrived problem, is there a useful case for this? I don't see how since there are no function patterns.